# Insert component instances into another component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been working on a specific layout system. The functionality would be a big form group, that is divided into tabs that we are able to navigate, after the form is valid you can save. After saving you'd see the status of each request going through, if the request fails you have an option to edit it and try again, for this i need to insert the tab that failed and this is where i am running into issues.
The status tracker for the request receives an array of tab component instances, which i would like to inject into the DOM. Injecting them is working to an extent, as they are in the DOM, but don't appear when i query for them with the @ContentChildren directive, which is a big issue in my scenario since i need to access the instances to be able to switch them. I know, a very convoluted explanation, but bear with me.

So Here is the input on the Status Tracker component, these would be the tabs that would have a failed request associated with them.

```
@Input() contents: TabContentComponent[];
```

I also have this elementRef of the container i want them to end up inside of

```
@ViewChild('InjectedTabsContainer') injectedTabsContainer: ElementRef;
```

This is how the HTML looks for the element where it would be inserted

```
 <app-tab-container [class.hidden]="!showFailedPortion">
  <div #InjectedTabsContainer></div>
 </app-tab-container>
```

Right now the way how i add them into the div is with this fn

```
private addTabsToDOM() {
this.contents.forEach(componentInstance => {
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.injectedTabsContainer.nativeElement,componentInstance);
});
```

}

Now the components do get to the intended location, one of them is visible and that's how it should be as only one is active at a time, but both when inspecting the tab-container
The problem is the tab-container instance doesn't recognize this, i assume cause i am only adding the elementRef and it's not the component itself

This is how i access the content instances in the tab-container

```
@ContentChildren(TabContentComponent) tabContents: QueryList<TabContentComponent>;
```

and this is how the HTML inside the tab-container looks like

```
<div class="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-start items-center" [ngSwitch]="getIsUploadStarted" (click)="printTabs()">

  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">
    <!--  Tab navigation panel -->
    <div class="w-7/12 max-sm:w-9/12 h-10 flex relative">
      <!--  Existing tabs    -->
      <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabContents">
        <app-tab class="h-10 flex-1 flex justify-start items-center"
                 *ngIf="tab"
                 [formValidationFns]="tab.formValidationFns"
                 (validationChangeEmitter)="checkAllGroups()"
                 (click)="handleSelectTab(tab)"
                 [iconName]="tab.iconName">
        </app-tab>
      </ng-container>
      <!--  Selection slider  -->
      <div #selectionSlider class="bg-light-accent-secondary hover:bg-light-accent-secondary-hover dark:bg-dark-accent-secondary dark:hover:bg-dark-accent-secondary-hover absolute bottom-0 h-full w-1 transition-all duration-700 ease-[cubic-bezier(.49,-0.51,.41,1.63)]"></div>
    </div>
    <!--  Content  -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true">
    <app-upload-progress-manager [existingTabs]="tabContents.toArray()"></app-upload-progress-manager>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I realize that this might not be a very good idea at all to make such DOM manipulation, but i need to preserve the state of each tab, and it's not something i could use the @Input decorator to carry over and create a new instance of the component.